# Change NTFS folder date when editing or adding a file (Windows)

Tags: windows, ntfs

Is it possible to update the date/time of the parent windows folders when editing or adding a file? 
(OS: Windows 7)

Only the first parent folder is being updated, it would be nice to update all parent folders.

Comment: http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-change-the-last-modified-date-creation-date-and-last-accessed-date-for-files-and-folders/

Comment: When you add a file (or folder) the modified date is already updated ...

Comment: You are right DavidPostill, I have edited the question now. Only the very parent folder is being updated, how to update all parent folders?